# How to check if node has property without instancing?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to check if a certain node type has a property
without actually needing to make an instance of it

like this:

```
print("z_index" in Position2D);
```

Answer (score 4):

### Classes in `ClassDB`

If we are talking about a build-in class (not a custom class that you created, but one that is part of Godot), you can use `ClassDB` to get the property:

```
var properties := ClassDB.class_get_property_list("Position2D")
```

---

### Classes from Godot Scripts

If the class is not in `ClassDB` (which is the case custom classes), but you have the script, you can use the script to get the property list:

```
var properties := preload("res://custom_class.gd").get_script_property_list()
```

---

If you don't have the script, perhaps you can find it. This code uses the hidden project setting `"_global_script_classes"` to find the path of the script for a class given the `name_of_class` you are looking for, and loads it:

```
if ProjectSettings.has_setting("_global_script_classes"):
    for x in ProjectSettings.get_setting("_global_script_classes"):
        if x.class == name_of_class:
            return load(x.path)
```

**Addendum**: For Godot 4 use `ProjectSettings.get_global_class_list()` instead:

```
for global_class in ProjectSettings.get_global_class_list():
    if global_class["class"] == name_of_class:
        return load(global_class["path"])
```

---

### Other classes

However, the above approach will not work for every type of script. In those cases, I'm afraid the best way is to instance it. You can still get the properties from the instance and cache them (perhaps put them in a dictionary) so that you are not creating a new instance every time you need to query:

```
var properties := (CustomClass.new()).get_property_list()
```

---

### Query the properties

Regardless of how you got the property list, you can query them the same way. For example this code looks for a property with name `"z_index"` and gets its type:

```
var found := false
var type := TYPE_NIL
for property in properties:
    if property.name == "z_index":
        found = true
        type = property.type
        break

prints(found, type)
```

*The type is a [Variant.Type](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@globalscope.html#enum-globalscope-variant-type) constant.*

Answer (score 2):

Theraot's answer is correct, since it provides a way to check attributes without creating an instance of a node/gdscript.

You can also check the properties of an existing instance of a node/scene by doing this:

```py
if "attribute_name" in thing:
  pass # do stuff here
```

Practical example; During a signal triggered by two Area2Ds colliding, check if one node's attribute `item_type` is set:

```py
func _on_area_2d_area_entered(area):
  if "item_type" in area:
    print(area["item_type"])
```

Comment: The question was "without instancing", here you have instances (`thing` and `area`). Furthermore this syntax works in Godot 3.

Comment: @Theraot you're right! I don't know how I missed that, thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer